# I have not captured a screenshot using the service

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, centos, sh

I am using a shell script and I want to run the script automatically when the system is **ON/Restart** without opening any application.

Here is my `script.sh` file:

```sh
while sleep 5 
do
scrot 'myimage.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Desktop/'
done
```

test.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script
   
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/chirag/tracker-ror/script.sh
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
> sudo systemctl status test.service

    ● test.service - My Shell Script
         Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-10-02 00:40:06 IST; 53s ago
       Main PID: 841 (script.sh)
          Tasks: 2 (limit: 18399)
         Memory: 2.1M
         CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
                 ├─  841 bin/bash /home/chirag/tracker-ror/script.sh
                 └─35186 scrot myimage.png -e mv $f ~/Desktop/
```

Below error is coming up:

```
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35166]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35168]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35170]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35172]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35174]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35176]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35178]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35181]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35184]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35186]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35188]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35190]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
    Oct 02 00:40:59 chirag-ThinkPad-T460 script.sh[35192]: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
```

Comment: Seems whatever that script is, it wants to contact the UI (X display) and it cannot. That makes some sense, it's a web server. What is the script supposed to do? Why are you using Ruby On Rails for a system service?

Comment: You can't be running Ubuntu and CentOS at the same time. There is no indication that you are actually running an X11 server, so apparently that is the problem, just like the error message says.

Comment: `scrot` uses the `DISPLAY` variable. Programs run under X11 (i.e. in the graphical environment) get the right value automatically. Programs run by a service do not.

Comment: I do not understand what you say

Comment: For `scrot` to work, there has to be an X11 server displaying things and `scrot` has to be able to communicate with it. Assuming there is a server, `scrot` needs the right value in the [`DISPLAY` variable](https://askubuntu.com/q/432255/693277). Programs started under X11 server inherit the variable, so you may be unaware of the mechanism and it simply works. A program run by a service has no means of knowing what `DISPLAY` you mean. It will also lack authorization to use the display. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469402/108618).